# If # sign is recognazible in AndroidManifest?

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest, android-xml

Has an interesting problem: I'm using `pathPrefix` attribute in my manifest and with value `android:pathPrefix="/example/"` all working normally whether value `android:pathPrefix="/#example/"` becomes unrecognizable. I'm definitely need an #(U+0023) sign to be in `pathPrefix`. Any solutions?

UPD:

1) tried to use `&#0023;`

2) also tried `\\u0023`

3) and `\\#`

4) and `\u0023`

Comment: `2) also tried \\u0023` - what about **\u0023**?

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi same result, nothing

Comment: In an URI, the fragment part starting from `#` is not part of the path. So of course it won't match as a path prefix either.

Comment: @laalto no ways to solve it? thanks for the answer, will try to solve on a site side